# useEffect issue on rendering updated/created/deleted data

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I am currently trying to do a habit tracker app, the functionality is all "good", but I am having rendering issues. When I POST/PUT/DELETE anything, it works, but in order to see the change I need to hard refresh so it is a clear issue on the useEffect or state and I am not the best at using useEffect so I don't know what to pass to the dependency array to make it re-render. I am kinda new to coding and react/nextjs so I apologize if my code is not the best.
https://ibb.co/dK2g5Hd

I tried adding the `habitsForCheckBox` on the dependency array but it doesn't stop rendering if I put it in the dependency array. That was my only guess as that is what is displaying the data. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please use code blocks, do not use images for code.

Answer (score 0):

Extract your code to get the habits from the useEffect in a separated function, then call that function in your useEffect and also after your POST/PUT/DELETE actions are completed

Comment: Oh so something like a "global" getAllHabits function where I will fetch, and then call it in my useEffect. And when you said, "also after your POST/PUT/DELETE actions are completed", you mean something like going to line 44, inside of the updateHabitCompletion function and call that function? Something like going to line 44 and simply calling getAllHabits() so that I fetch again by calling that function?

Comment: Exactly! notice that this works because your AJAX calls are using await, so calling getAllHabits() after you call the fetch method is totally fine!  PS1: If you find my answers helpful pls mark it as the answer, ty! PS2: Next time don't share an image, would be better to paste your code in a service like codesandbox.io so we can play around, regards.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the POST/PUT/DELETE to update the data that you are showing, you need to refetch it. There are certainly a lot of patterns for doing this.

One option would be to abstract the fetching to its own function and call it everytime you do any mutation on the data. In this case making a custom hook would make things easier.

```js
const [data, refetch] = useGetHabits();
```

Something like this would let you use `data` everywhere and `refetch` whenever you update it which would already make sure `data` is up to date.

This is the approach taken by a library like [useSWR](https://swr.vercel.app/) with the `mutate` function (which if called with no attributes it refetches the data). This is a really useful library made by the same team as NextJS which you could look into using.

A custom hook is also useful to "hook" into the lifecycle of the JS `Promise`. All async functions return Promise, and this Promise's state helps define whether or not the async value is ready or not. By using a custom hook, you can handle this lifecycle really easily (without doing `await` on the spot all the time) and add a nice loading indicator while things are loading. `useSWR` also handles this. Something like the following would be a common pattern.

```js
const { data, error, mutate } = useSWR(url);

if (error) {
  return <ErrorIndicator error={error} />;
}

if (!data && !error) {
  return <LoadingIndicator />;
}

return <MyComponent data={data} onUpdate={() => mutate()} />;
```

Another option would be to return the data from the API everytime you update/delete/create. This way all your calls would immediately be able to update the UI with fresh data.